# Unclear reasoning on why orthogonality implies non-correlation/independence in linear regression

Tags: statistics, independence, linear-regression

in courses, I have come across the reasoning below at least twice, but I don't understand it. It's in the context of linear regression.

[image]

e is a raw residual.
I don't know what is meant by "assumption of linearity". I agree that, denoting H the projection matrix on the column space of X, the matrix of covariates, we have:
$$X^Te=(e^TX)^T=(y^T(I-H)X)^T=0$$

How does this relate to correlation?
I assume empirical correlation is meant, because the matrix X is fixed and not a random variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption of linearity means we assume the linear model
$$y=X \beta + \epsilon$$
where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ is observed and fixed, the coefficients $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^p$ are unobserved and fixed, and the noise term $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is unobserved and random. We do observe the response $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, but it's random thru its dependence on $\epsilon$.
In short, the assumption of linearity basically means $y$ depends linearly on $X$.
An OLS estimator $\hat{\beta}_{OLS}$ of $\beta$ is defined to be any vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^p$ that minimizes $|y-Xb|^2$. Then we define the residual vector $e:=y-X \hat{\beta}_{OLS}$. Your statement and derivation that $X^\top e= \mathbf{0}_p$ is correct.
As for why this relates to correlation, note each column $X_j$ of $X$ corresponds to a feature, which are rows of $X^\top$:
$$X^\top = \begin{pmatrix}X_1^\top \\ \vdots \\ X_p^\top \end{pmatrix}$$
Here we actually need 1 more assumption that the intercept is a feature, eg $X_1= \mathbf{1}_n$. Then $X^\top e= \mathbf{0}_p$ implies
$$0= \mathbf{1}_n^\top e= \sum_{i=1}^ne_i$$
In other words, the residuals have mean zero.
Now consider any other feature, eg $X_2$. Its sample covariance with the residuals is defined as
$$\text{Cov}(X_2,e):= \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_{i2}- \bar{x}_2)(e_i- \bar{e})$$
Since the residuals have zero mean, $\bar{e}=0$ so
$$\text{Cov}(X_2,e)= \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_{i2}- \bar{x}_2)e_i= 
\frac{1}{n-1}\big\{ \sum_{i=1}^nx_{i2}e_i- \bar{x}_2 \sum_{i=1}^ne_i \big\}$$
Again using $\sum_{i=1}^ne_i=0$, we have
$$ \text{Cov}(X_2,e)= \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i2}e_i= \frac{1}{n-1}X_2^\top e =0$$
Since zero covariance is the same as being uncorrelated, this shows how the dot product relates

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood you question, but take this as a sort of proof of why this is so:

1. Assume you have two lines, A and B, which are orthogonal
2. Change your coordinate system so that A lines up with the X axis
3. Now B will end up lining up with Y or Z
4. This means that A is a function purely of X, and B of Z/Y, so they depend on completely different variables, hence they are uncorrelated

Comment: To be honest I don't really understand what your reasoning is

Comment: The point is that correlation is defined as a relationship between two variables, and that orthogonal lines are not correlated because by reframing the problem, it's possible to make them not even share a dimension in 2-3d space

Comment: I'd also like to note this is not only in linear regression, it's just the way lines work

Comment: I understand what you are doing in terms of "how lines work". IIn the context of random variables, I have never thought in this way. So you are saying that the set of random variables on a given probability space is a vector space? Is it finite-dimensional (I don't think so)? Somehow I'm trying to digest if this type of reasoning is "legal"

Comment: The inner product is zero, equivalent to that in linear algebra 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12128/what-does-orthogonal-mean-in-the-context-of-statistics/16315#16315